# postgres trigger to update another table based on a column value

Tags: postgresql

I don't know anything about stored procs. But desperately need one to run an update sql when a boolean column in a table changes value from false to true. If someone could provide one it will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a test table

```
CREATE TABLE test20120524
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  bool boolean,
  comment_by_trigger text,
  CONSTRAINT pk_test20120524 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=TRUE
);
```

This is a sample trigger function. `OLD` and `NEW` are pre-declared variables that means the updated row.

```
create or replace function test1() returns opaque as
'
declare
    -- some variables
begin
    if OLD.bool = false and NEW.bool = true then
        NEW.comment_by_trigger = ''affected by trigger'';
    end if;
    return NEW;
end;
' language 'plpgsql';
```

Then, create trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test2
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON test20120524
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE test1();
```

Stored Procedures are not so difficult. You can learn it easily in PostgreSQL official documents : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/index.html

see

- 36.. Triggers
- 39.. PL/pgSQL - SQL Procedural Language (especially 39.9 Trigger Procedures)

Comment: Thank you so much, its one of those things where the req comes in at night and you want it done by next day morn, and there is not much time to dig around. Thank you soo much